# how to remove excerpt on category archive page in genesis framework?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I am trying to remove the excerpt ( content ) from the category archive page so only the title shown on the page, not the content.

I am currently trying the code below with no luck?

does anybody have any suggestions?

```
  add_action ( 'genesis_before_entry' , 'designody_remove_entry_content_archives' );
function designody_remove_entry_content_archives() {
if (in_category('5')) {
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
}
}
```

my second solution... also not working

```
function replace_content( $output) {
if (is_category('5')) {
return '' ;
}
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'replace_content' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fully satisfactory Genesis-specific solution, and I'd be curious to know what StudioPress itself says, but I do have WordPress solutions.

First, to use the Genesis hook and a condition, you need to wrap it in a function:

To quote the Codex: "Warning: You can only use conditional query tags after the posts_selection action hook in WordPress (the wp action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

The following works to remove the excerpt on the specified category archive page:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'remove_content_on_category_pages' ) ; 

function remove_content_on_category_pages() {

    if ( is_category( '5' ) ) {

        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );

    }

}
```

However, the `in_category()` conditional - which should help with entry content when it appears in other archives (categories, blog, etc.) - doesn't seem to work.

In order to get the desired results as I understand them - no post content, in this implementation "the excerpt", for this category on any type of archive page, but preserving it for individual posts - you can revert to the trusty `the_content filter`, but note that the `the_content` can be a tricky and powerful tool subject to unexpected secondary effects. That said, on a vanilla Genesis installation, the following tests out:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'test_gen_content' ) ;

function test_gen_content( $content ) {
    
    /**
    apply to all secondary queries don't apply if single page or post, or in 
    admin, otherwise obliterate - can use is_single() instead of is_singular()
    if only posts are at issue 
    **/
    if ( ! is_singular() && ! is_admin() && in_category( '157' ) ) {
    
        return '' ;
        
    }
    
    return $content ;
    
}
```

I must say, however, that, given the peculiarities and complications of the Genesis framework, and the peculiarity of the request, out there in the wild I'd be very tempted to use a CSS kludge, shaped to requirements - at least failing direct instruction or intervention from a Genesis maven or StudioPress itself. Whether you needed to refine the CSS further to suit your particular installation, I can't say, but it might be a lot easier, actually, then sorting out the PHP even with the correct hooks etc.

```
//substitute appropriate category slug for "development-forums"
.home .category-development-forums .entry-content,
.blog .category-development-forums .entry-content,
.archive .category-development-forums .entry-content
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: you are correct it needs an add_action hook, See my complete code above.

Comment: IMO you ought to update your main post to indicate that your edit constitutes a solution. Otherwise, the question doesn't make sense. Also, of course, you ought to show my own answer some love ;) Either way, congratulations on getting your issue handled.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, when you switch from is_category to in_category, that means that all posts in that category, regardless of where they come up, should have the content removed, not just posts on the particular category archive page.

Comment: the question still stands.  I did try in_category vs is_category before with no luck.

Comment: Wait a second - are you trying to remove the excerpt for each post in the archive - or something else? Anyway, I thought you meant that you had settled on "complete code." So, you're still looking for a solution, right?

Comment: the original issue still persists. The snippet of code that I gave you before was the if statement. Now I added the add_action function.

Comment: I have also tried this WordPress function but does not work. 

function replace_content( $output) {
if (is_category('13')) {
return '' ;
}
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'replace_content' );

Comment: See updated answer. Still looking for the "right" rather than possibly good enough answer.

Comment: See re-updated answer. Let us know if you find the Genesis-correct solution!